# Testing functionality based on HTML5 DOM-methods

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm wondering how to test functionality based on HTML5 DOM-methods. Like the new dialog-API for example.

Consider the following function;

```
function show(dialog)
{
    if(typeof(dialog.showModal) !== "function")
        throw new Error("Update your browser");
    dialog.showModal();
}
```

I want to make sure that

1. an error is thrown when the method is not available
2. dialog.showModal is called if available

I'm currently running karma + jasmine with the firefox and chrome launchers but none of them seems to support the dialog-API.

Can I shim this in some kind of way? Can I create a function on all dialog DOM nodes?

I could do the following

```
var modal = document.createElement("dialog");
Object.defineProperty(modal, "showModal", {
    value: function()
    {
        console.log("hello world!");
    }
});
```

however, that isn't carried over to other instances of a dialog.

This is a very simplified example of what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Most browsers use prototype inheritance, so you could add the method to the [*HTMLDialogElement.prototype*](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/semantics.html#the-dialog-element), however that has long been considered a [*bad idea*](http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/).

Comment: Could you perhaps use "Modernizr" to check if the functionality exists?

Comment: @RobG Ah, yes, that would make perfect sense for testing purposes actually. Thanks for the links! If you could post your comment as an answer I will gladly accept it.

Comment: @alykhalid Testing if the functionality exists is not the problem per se, it's making sure I'm covering all the bases that's the issue. I need to make sure the method is called as well as the errorhandling is on point.

Answer (score 0):

**This is what polyfills are: an attempt to shim support for newer specs into browsers that don't support them**. What you're talking about is essentially creating a polyfill for the `<dialog>` element.

**Some older ECMAScript 6 specs specified a function to test if something existed and was a function, but this seems to have been scrapped in more recent specs**. This is a "polyfill" for that (in whatever way that term can apply to a scrapped spec), both as an example of polyfilling and as a tool we'll use to explore the concept further:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    var ops = Object.prototype.toString;

    Function.isFunction = function(o) {
        return ops.call(o) === "[object Function]";
    };
}());
```

**Note that we have to cache the original Object.prototype.toString**: most JavaScript runtimes override it in Function.prototype.toString, and we really need to be calling the original. This should give you an idea of how fiddly and error-prone polyfilling can be: even in a case like this where the code is short and simple, nuances like using `Object.prototype.toString.call(o)` instead of `o.toString()` are still critical.

Anyway, once you've got this function, it becomes much easier to test for things like modal support:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    var test = document.createElement("dialog");
    if (!Function.isFunction(test.showModal)) {
        throw new Error("HTMLDialogElement.showModal() is not supported");
    };
}());
```

**To modify all dialog element instances, you would extend the prototype that most immediately pertains to that object**. In the case of the HTML dialog spec, that's HTMLDialogElement. You could do something like this:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    var HTMLDialogElement = HTMLDialogElement; //undefined if unsupported

    if (!Function.isFunction(HTMLDialogElement)) {
        // No native dialog support
        throw new Error("No support for <dialog> elements");
    }

    if (!Function.isFunction(HTMLDialogElement.prototype.showModal)) {
        // The interface exists, but showModal isn't supported
        HTMLDialogElement.prototype.showModal = function () {
            console.log("Hello world!");
        };
     }
}());
```

**If there's no support for the prototype either, then things get trickier**. An unknown element doesn't get a distinctive prototype; it's just an HTMLElement (like all other elements, eventually). So to make a function work for `<dialog>` elements in an unsupported environment, you'd have to add it to *all* elements. Still, you can sort of make it work:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    HTMLElement.prototype.showModal = function () {
        if (this.tagName !== "DIALOG") {
            throw new TypeError("showModal() called on non-dialog");
        }
        console.log("Hello world!");
    };
}());
```

Most polyfills work based on compromises like this: they don't support the spec perfectly, but do well enough to support common use cases.

**Be warned: polyfilling extends native objects, and this is commonly considered bad practice**. Most people who call it bad practice will make an exception for polyfills, but the rule is still considered good even though polyfills are so useful. That should give you an idea of how complex and error-prone the task can be. This is black magic: not a task to be undertaken lightly.